# Connect validates_exclusion_of bad words to a separate file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a long list of terms I would like to prevent from entry into a field using `validates_exclusion_of`. This list is getting very long, and some of the terms in it may be inappropriate/offensive/distracting/procrastination-inducing for other programmers. Is there a way to connect the following code to a separate plain text document held somewhere on my repo?

```
validates_exclusion_of :path, :in => %w( long list of bad words ... ), :message => "This is a protected word. Please try another."
```

Bonus: this message doesn't display on my form when a user enters one of these terms. How do I get the message to display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't have to use validates_exclusion_of you can just define your own validate

```
validate :check_bad_words

def check_bad_words
  @bad_words ||= File.read('badwords.txt').split
  errors.add_to_base("#{path} is a protected word. Please try another.") if @bad_words.include? path
end
```

for your error message to show up on the form, in older rails it is
<%= f.error_messages %>   where f is the form

for rails 3.x i think you have to do it yourself as per [f.error_messages in Rails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873190/f-error-messages-in-rails-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

To display the message you need in your form something like this (haml example)

```
- if @object.errors.any?
  #error_explanation= error_messages_for :object
```