# DEPRECATION WARNING: f.error_messages was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

DEPRECATION WARNING: f.error_messages was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin. Please install it with `rails plugin install git://`...

Seems a bit extreme to use a plugin for error messages like this.  Am I not using the right standard names or something?

The code (HAML) is:

```
- simple_form_for(@link) do |f|
  = f.error_messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Michal. I will give you an upvote.
I found that the following was a good quick replacement for the upgrade:

```
  -if @link.errors.any?
    %div#error_explanation
      %h2
        =pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error")+' '
        prohibited this link from being saved:
      %ul
      -@link.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li
          =msg
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no misspelling in your code, f.error_messages are deprecated in fact. There is a discussion on stackoverflow: [f.error_messages in Rails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873190/f-error-messages-in-rails-3-0).

Answer (score 1):

You could install the `dynamic_form` gem which supports a few helpers for your Rails 3 models. One of this helpers is error_messages. So the code below, that use to work on a Rails 2.3.x app, will still work on Rails 3 without deprecation warnings.

```
<% form_for @video, :html=>{:multipart=>true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...more view code...
<% end %>
```