# form_for error messages in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the preferred way to display validation error messages using `form_for` in Rails 4?

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873190/f-error-messages-in-rails-3-0#answer-13246663

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same as Rails 3 -- see [f.error_messages in Rails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873190/f-error-messages-in-rails-3-0) or http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3 for many different possibilities.

My personal preference is to use simple_form and have it put the error next to the input.

Answer (score 34):

This is how I am displaying them for my form object called `@location:`

```
<% if @location.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @location.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Note: put the above code after the `<%= form_for @location do |f| %>` line

Answer (score 17):

My preferred way of doing this and keeping the code simple and DRY, is the following:

Create a new helper inside of **application_helper.rb**

```
# Displays object errors
def form_errors_for(object=nil)
  render('shared/form_errors', object: object) unless object.blank?
end
```

Create a new shared partial in **shared/_form_errors.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :form_errors do %>
  <p>
    <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> prevented the form from being saved:
  </p>

  <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Edit your **application.html.erb** file to include the errors where you want them:

```
<%= yield :form_errors %>
```

Finally, place the helper at the start of each form:

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>
  <%= form_errors_for @model %>

  <%# ... form fields ... %>
<% end %>
```

This makes it *extremely* simple to manage and show your form errors across many forms.

Comment: Thank you very much! In Rails 4.x its very important to create a folder called "shared" so the partial can be called correctly, otherwise you would get an ActionView::MissingTemplate error.

Comment: In the example above, does <%= yield :form_errors %> replace the standard <%= yield %> or it is in addition to?  What does adding :form_errors to yield do vs the standard yield?

Comment: No, it does not replace it. The standard yield has a completely different use as it renders the view in the layout.

Comment: <%= yield :form_errors %> is equivalent to <%= content_for :form_errors %>, which may be easier to understand (it's just printing out the html you stored in that key previously)

Comment: nice job.  saved me time.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what was asked, but if you are using the simple_form gem, which I recommend, you can use f.error_notification which takes :message as an option.

```
= f.error_notification message: form_errors_for(your_object)
```

I use a method pretty similar to Wes's answer; form_errors_for inside **application_helper.rb**

```
def form_errors_for_base(object)
  if object.errors.messages[:base].present?
    object.errors.messages[:base].join(",\n") + "."
  else
    nil
  end
end
```