# How to display error messages for a devise form? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

```
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %></p>
      <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></p>
 <%= end =%>
```

I am trying to create a basic login form.  I want to be able to display an error like "wrong user info" if the username or password is incorrect.  I looked at this post here:  [form_for error messages in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662089/form-for-error-messages-in-rails-4)

but it doesn't seem to work for devise forms?

Answer (score 2):

***First of all you must put notice alerts***

```
<% if alert %>
  <div id="notice_wrapper">
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  </div>
<% elsif notice %>
  <div id="notice_wrapper">
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

i personally use something like this.

To write your own devise errors you must modify it by yourself. 
Devise errors located at:

```
config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

Comment: Okay so I would be creating something similar to what you wrote in the config/locales/devise.en.yml file but how would I get the errors to actually display on the page?  Thank you by the way.

Comment: You must have `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` to your views. In top of the form underneath of the form_for line. Also you can modify the div to your css to style the error displaying

Comment: Thank you again.  And just to clarify one last time, what file would I be putting the <% if alert %> type code in?  My new.html.erb file or something else?

Comment: to the layouts/application.html.erb file after <body> tag.