# Trying to use validations with local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

So I've been trying to use validations on ruby on rails with the form_for format

I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048292/8054234

but im getting the following error:

```
<%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> prevented the form from being saved:

undefined method `errors' for :user:Symbol
```

Any idead how I could make this work/fix it?

edit1 uploaded full form code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "users" %>

<div class="jumbotron"
    <div class="container">

    <h2>Signup</h2>


<%= form_for :user, url: '/users' do |f| %>
  <%= form_errors_for :user %>
  Número de Empregado: <br>
  <%= f.number_field :NumeroEmpregado %><br>
  Primeiro e Último Nome: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :nome %><br>
  Password: <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br>
  Confirmação Password: <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br>


  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Post your full form code.

Comment: Done, edited main question

Comment: You got the answer @yzalavin is right :)

Comment: Replace `<%= form_errors_for :user %>` To ` <%= form_errors_for f.object %>`

Comment: This fixed the error, but the error message is still not showing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

In your `UsersController` in `new` action update as below

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

and in your `views/users/_form.html.erb` file form do the below code

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  Número de Empregado: <br>
  <%= f.number_field :NumeroEmpregado %><br>

  Primeiro e Último Nome: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :nome %><br>

  Password: <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br>

 Confirmação Password: <br>
 <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br>

 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: gives me this error: `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass`

on this line  `<% if f.object.errors.any? %>`

Comment: Updated this line `<%= pluralize(f.object.errors.count, "error") %>`

Comment: I get this error on `line 3 => <% if f.object.errors.any? %>`

Comment: Use `User` model object with `form_for` like this `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>` where `@user` is `@user = User.new` in your controller

Comment: did it, now I get the following error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` on line `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`

Comment: have you created `@user = User.new` in your controller from where this page rendering?

Comment: yes: `def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'

    end
  end
`

Comment: Done this, code works, but It's still not showing the error messages when I submit the form empty...

Comment: what is the console output? does it redirect back to the same form page?

Comment: redirects back to the same page yes, but without displaying any error message for the fields being empty

Answer (score 2):

`object` must be an instance of an ActiveRecord model. You are passing `:user` as a symbol.

You should pass an instance of User. If you use some authentication logic you could pass `current_user` to this method.

UPD:

The error says that your `object` does not understand method `errors`. `:user` is a Symbol. It is not a variable that holds your user. Therefore, it does not implement method `errors`.

`User` is a model that inherits behaviour from `ActiveRecord`. It provides method `errors`. For example, `object = User.create(params)` will work.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? I'm quite new to RoR and I don't quite understand what you want me to do, sorry